# I don't have session.payment_intent in stripe

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I had implemeted stripe wallet in next.js and I created a test account for developing.

**this is my server_side codes : **

**checkout_session.js**

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_xxxxx"
);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
          {
            // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
            price: "price_1NhWxaIjDax7Fiks0djPOJXF",
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: "payment",
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      console.log(session);
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
      // res.status(200).json({ client_secret: session.payment_intent });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
  }
}
```

after successfully payment, I did not have client_secret in session.payment_intent and when I loged it by console.log, I relized that my payment_intent property is null

im using test mode and test data for payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout Sessions don't return a Payment Intent object since API version 2022-08-01:
https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01
Instead, you will find it in the Session once it is completed (`checkout.session.completed` event).

If you want your code to work, you'd have to hardset an older version like 2020-08-27 (although you should go along with the changes made):
https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/set-version

I'm confused as to why you want the `client_secret` though. You can't confirm Payment Intents created by Checkout Sessions, they confirm themselves when the Customer completes the Session.

Comment: thank you, but I want to add success payment info and their information into database after their paying

Comment: "After their paying" - that wouldn't be after your Session is created, as I mentioned that would only be once the Session is completed (hence why the Payment Intent only populates at the point nowadays). When you get the `checkout.session.completed` event, you can handle your process then. Also, if you want to show your customer a custom message for their payment, check this out:  
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page